# Authorizing by the parent model in rails using possibly pundit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorization, pundit

I a simple relation

```
class Rental < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :offers, dependent: :delete_all
end
```

and

```
class Offer < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :rental
end
```

Within the `OffersController` I'm performing a few checks regardin the create action which currently looks like

```
class OffersController < ApplicationController
    def create
        unless current_user.stripe_id?
          return redirect_to billing_path, alert: "No stripe id."
        end
        
        if @rental && @rental.user_id == current_user.id
          redirect_to(request.referer, alert: "Invalid action.") && return
        end
        
        if current_user.offers.accepted.any?
          redirect_to(request.referer, alert: "Already accepted offer.") && return
        end
        
        if Offer.exists?(user_id: current_user.id)
          redirect_to(request.referer, alert: "Invalid.") && return
        end
    end
end
```

and what I would like to achieve is to remove all these checks from the contoller to clean it up and supposedly this would be handled by pundit very well.

My issue is that if I create an `OfferPolicy` I have that

```
class OfferPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :offer

  def initialize(user, offer)
    @user = user
    @offer = offer
  end

  def create?
    user.stripe_id?
  end  
end
```

which would take care of the first check, but I ran into problems when I had to authorize within the offers controller using the paren record `@rental`. How should this be done? It would seem that I would need to authorize using some rental policy which I at the moment don't have at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are mixing responsibilities. I recommend using pundit only for user authorization and what it was designed for. If you want to separate business logic from your controller, I recommend using other gems like [Interactor](https://github.com/collectiveidea/interactor).